# Every other message missing with Rabbit MQ

Tags: python, ruby, rabbitmq

We have a RabbitMQ server running under Docker. We both publish and receive messages from code in both Ruby and Python, all of which is almost exactly straight from the online tutorial examples. After a short number of messages, the Python version starts to only receives every other message. The Ruby script continues to receive all of them.

While not exactly RabbitMQ experts, we've checked the code and it's so close the official tutorials that it's hard to see that we're making any big mistakes. Plus it works initially anyway.

Is there anything that could be causing this odd behaviour?

Comment: It would probably help to see the code in question.

Comment: How do you publish and consume? Exclusive consumer? Fan-Out? Does your Python script die?

Comment: [mcve], please. It's almost impossible to answer a question like this without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as hinted at by Pascal, was that it needed to be set to 'Fan-Out'. Thanks for the tip.